# Smart contract to buy a service

Tags: contract-development, transactions, tokens

I want to work on a smart contract that manages monthly subscription purchases on my website.

Is this a valid usecase for smartcontract?

I read a lot of tutorial on smart contract but dont see a way to do that, because I need to link somehow an account on my website to an eth adress (the subscriber).

Comment: Maybe you can but you need to develop a dApp for it... the dApp will be registry the privetkey and who have the token off payment and use it for subscription

Answer (score 1):

Doing a monthly subscription service is not that easy with a smart contract because the price of the subscription will fluctuate as wildly as the price of the underlying ether.

For example, less than a month ago, I think the price of ether was under $500.00 US. Now it's over $1,100. That's the first problem you'll have to solve if you want to use a smart contract for a monthly subscription.

The most likely reason you haven't seen an example or tutorial of this is probably that it can get very complicated. In fact, I don't think I've seen a working example of a workable subscription-based service, but I may have missed it.